# Array doesnt give an Out of bounds Error Message while picking a Random item C#/Unity

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, random, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a beginner question. Why does this code not result in an error message?

```
public Tile[] tiles = new Tile[2];
...
SetTile(0, 0, 0, nocollide, tiles[Random.Range(0,2)]);
```

The Array is has two items in it but I pick a value from 0 to two, which are three items. When I make it to 0,1 it just picks the first item. But why?

Comment: Is that [this `Random.Range`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html)? Then it returns a float, making it hit 2.0 exactly rather unlikely (but not impossible). And any 1.9999999999 would be truncated down to 1. – You should use a random function that gives you integers instead.

Comment: because Random.Range method return a number that in range of [0,2) which means the result can be 1,0 but it cannot be 2

Comment: (oh, didn’t see that int-based overload; the documentation has odd formatting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static int Range(int min, int max);
```

**Description**

The reason is simple, Return a random integer number between min [**inclusive**] and max [**exclusive**] (Read Only).

max is **exclusive**. Random.Range(0, 10) can return a value between 0 and 9.

If you want to include the max value then you can use the below-overloaded method.

```
public static float Range(float min, float max);
```

**Description**

Return a random float number between min [**inclusive**] and max [**inclusive**] (Read Only).

max is **inclusive**. Random.Range(0.0f, 1.0f) can return 1.0 as the value.

**Reference:** https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html

Comment: @PeterPeperoni SO is best platform to learn and share